# D7 Commerce - Save rules applied to line items in cart?

Tags: 7

I want my users to be able to redeem points for discounts off of their orders. Every dollar is worth 20 points. I've managed to work the entire equation in Rules to line items, however none of the rules I put into place save. Here is what I have so far:

[image]

[image]

As soon as I leave my cart, the value changes from the discounted value I've set, back to 0.00. For some reason, the updated unit price will not save (even though I've set it to?) Am I missing something? Apologies for crazy rule, but it's the only way I could get it done.

**Update:** I've learned that Cart Refresh is the reason rules applied to line items in cart don't save. How can I make these rules stick?!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. You will have to:

1. Add a Discount `/admin/commerce/discounts`, which will generate a discount rule. `/admin/config/workflow/rules?event=0&tag=Commerce%20Discount`
2. Edit the discount Rule and do your magic here.
3. Create a Coupon `/admin/commerce/coupons` and link it to your Discount in the "Discount Reference" field.

Comment: This makes sense, but it still doesn't explain how to set the discount value with my calculated value? E.g. Rules won't allow me to subtract a decimal or integer from the cart total (as it is of type 'Price').

Comment: See updated above!

Comment: I've figured this out, and will post answer later for those who are curious :) !